# How to have 3 check boxes with their labels on a single line

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to have three check boxes and their label in a single line as I have shown below.

I tried having check boxes inside table cells but the label is coming above the check box.I am a beginner in HTML.

So please provide me with a possible solution.

Thanks in advance!!!

> USA[]----------------------------------ENGLAND[]----------------------------------AUSTRALIA[]

Here, by **`[]`** - I mean a **check box**.These three columns should uniformly occupy the html form's width.

Here i have used **`----------------------------`** to show that I want this much space between a check box of the first and label of the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... or you can use a 1 x 1 table and keep it simple! You will be able to apply limited styling to each element using this approach.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="country1"></td>
        <td>India</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="country2"></td>
        <td>Greece</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="country3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use either table or div,span

for table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Hindi</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>English</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>French</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But by using div,span you have to wright down some **Style**.

if you are using framework **Bootstrap** you can see more with less css [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

## [Here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kzh9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have all this elements in single `div` with its `display:inline`. With 3 child divs having uniform widths.

```
<div style="display:inline" style=" width:100%">
    <div style=" width:33%; float:left">USA<input type="checkbox"></div>
    <div style=" width:33%;float:left">ENGLAND<input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div style=" width:33%;float:left">Australia<input type="checkbox"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post the code for the table that you did, we can help you better, but you can do it like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="white-space: normal;">USA<input type="checkbox" /></div></td>
        <td><div style="white-space: normal;">ENGLAND<input type="checkbox" /></div></td>
        <td><div style="white-space: normal;">AUSTRALIA<input type="checkbox" /></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not question requested

Comment: @Madhawas So what did he requested then? From his explanation, it seems this is the structure that he tried and I'm just fixing it for him with `<div style="white-space: normal;">`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

---

```
    <form>
    <div class="chk">
        <label><input type="checkbox" /> USA</label>
    </div>
    <div class="chk">
        <label><input type="checkbox" /> ENGLAND</label>
    </div>
    <div class="chk">
        <label><input type="checkbox" /> AUSTRALIA</label>
    </div>
<form>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.chk
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
input {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8EGn/5068/)

**Output:**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;">
            <label>Hindi</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div  style="float:left;width:100px;" >

            <label>English</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div  style="float:left;width:100px;">

            <label>French</label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/7kzh9/1/